# Ninja Forms onsubmit button in form function

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am trying to add `onsubmit="return blahblah();"` inside the `<form>` element. However, it just echo's outside of the form every single time.

```
function ninja_forms_add_on_submit( $form_id ) {
  echo 'onsubmit="something"';
}
add_action( 'ninja_forms_display_open_form_tag', 'ninja_forms_add_on_submit' );
```

Been going through the actions documentation: http://ninjaforms.com/documentation/developer-api/actions/

The reason why im doing this is because i want the onsubmit to fire an ajax call before it starts the action.

Thanks again

Comment: So if you want to fire an ajax call before submitting a form why not just write a jquery method to catch the submit, e.preventdefault, do ajax call, then finally submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have realized the function you assigned to be executed on ninja_forms_display_open_form_tag  will be executed as soon, as the Ninja Forms renders the opening `form` tag; but the opening tag also includes the closing `>` - so there is no way to actually set the `onsubmit` attribute, or any attributes for that matter.

As mentioned by Culyx in the comments you could assign the onsubmit callback with jQuery.